# Moq unable to compare Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, mstest

I have c# application that I am building some tests using Moq. For one of my endpoints a user can pass one of several parameters, this is used to build a lambda that queries the database:

```
var existingCriteria = await _criteriaService.GetCriteriaBy(e =>
    e.IsActive &&
    e.Crop == request.Crop &&
    e.Region == request.Region &&
    e.Market == request.Market &&
    e.ProductStage == request.ProductStage &&
    e.Trait == request.Trait &&
    e.HarvestType == request.HarvestType
);
```

For my particular test, I only care about 2 parameters and I'm using this input for GetCriteriaBy

```
var request = new CriteriaRequest
{
    Crop = "Corn",
    Region = "NA"
};

var response = await new CriteriaController(_criteriaService.Object).AddCriteria(request);
```

Then my mock service is setup like this:

```
Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>> matchExpression = x =>
    x.IsActive == true &&
    x.Crop == "Corn" &&
    x.Region == "NA" &&
    x.Market == null && 
    x.ProductStage == null &&
    x.Trait == null && 
    x.HarvestType == null; 

mock.Setup(cr => cr.GetCriteriaBy(It.Is<Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>>>(x => Lambda.Equals(x, matchExpression))))
    .ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>> where) =>
    {
        return new List<CriteriaResponse>() {
            new CriteriaResponse {
                Id = 1,
                Crop = "Corn",
                Region = "NA"
            }
        };
    });
```

But it is never catching my test case in the `Setup`. If I switch the `It.Is` to an `It.IsAny` it works, but then all my tests are caught by this Setup and I only want some tests to have a response here.

What can I do to fix my Setup function to work as expected?

Comment: Instead of trying to match the lambda, you could use it in your ReturnsAsync to determine what to return.  Create a `List<CriteriaReponse>` of all the test responses and just do a `Where(where)` on that to determine what to return.

Comment: The problem with that is the return type is different than the `where` type. As in it uses `Criteria` to query but returns `CriteriaResponse`. If there is a way to parse the `where` query that could work?

Comment: Have you looked into how `Lambda.Equals()` actually works? (I don't know the `Lambda` class, and cannot find any documentation for it)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is what you originally wanted, but I think you can achieve it (with slightly less code than in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366158/moq-unable-to-compare-lambda-expression#answer-76366418)) by compiling the expression and then invoking it with an object that fits the filtering.

Something along the lines of:

```
mock.Setup(cr => cr.GetCriteriaBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>> expr) =>
    {
        var isCornMatch = expr.Compile().Invoke(new Criteria { IsActive = true, Crop = "Corn" });

        if (isCornMatch)
        {
            return new List<CriteriaResponse>
            {
                new CriteriaResponse {
                    Id = 1,
                    Crop = "Corn",
                    Region = "NA"
                }
            };
        }
        
        return new List<CriteriaResponse>();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for a better solution, but here is what I used to make it work:

```
mock.Setup(cr => cr.GetCriteriaBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>> where) =>
    {
        var criteria = new List<Criteria>()
        {
            new Criteria(){
                Id = 1,
                Crop = "Corn",
                Region = "NA"
            }
        };

        IQueryable<Criteria> query = criteria.AsQueryable();
        var filtered = query.Where(where);

        var response = new List<CriteriaResponse>();
        foreach (var item in filtered)
        {
            response.Add(new CriteriaResponse()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Crop = item.Crop,
                Region = item.Region
            });
        }

        return response;
    });
```

This seems like a lot of code to replicate something that should work in Moq.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is happening because of a mismatch in the lambda expression. For example, `IsActive` is really supposed to be `true` based on the search criteria?

Try simply:

```cs
Expression<Func<Criteria, bool>> matchExpression = x =>
    x.Crop == "Corn" &&
    x.Region == "NA";
```

If you narrow the scope of the match expression, your chances of landing a hit increase.

Comment: I tried narrowing down the fields and the `IsActive == true` was one of my attempts of tweaking the input to match, but no luck. In my controller it is mapping the `request` to all of the fields in the lambda, even if they are null. My guess is there is some meta difference between the lambda's but I cannot find it.

Comment: I see, it must be `Lambda.Equals(x, matchExpression)` cannot find a match because the expression trees are diff even though logically they are the same. Can you reproduce the whole expression via a debugger? I wonder if you are able to see the entire thing.